# How to repeat one element in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want repeat one image element in JSX, my required code is like as below:

```
<View>
  <Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />
  <Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />
  <Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />
  <Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />
  <Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />
</View>
```

How i can use a loop to generate this code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy! You can create an array on the fly. Like this:

```
<View>
  {[...Array(5)].map((x, i) => <Image key={i} source={require('../images/image.png')} />)}
</View>
```

The `[...Array(5)]` gives: `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`. Which might look useless, but actually, this gives us something to iterate over with `map()` which we can use to return the Components we want (we don't need `x` here at all).

You could, to improve performance, create the array outside your render to prevent re-creating the temporary array on each re-render. You can also put your `require` separately for similar reasons.

Comment: Also please remember to supply a key.

Comment: would you want to add a key?

Comment: Using the index as the key will trigger a warning, though in this case, it's not a problem.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, no, it shouldn't. It only warns if you don't provide one at all. Are you referring to some lint-rule perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a variable before you return your jsx.

Example:

```
const myjsx = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   myjsx.push(<Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />);
}
```

then in your final JSX you simply print out the {myjsx}

```
<View>
    {myjsx}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a short function to do this for you

`let func = () => (<Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />)
<View>
  {func()}
  {func()}
  {func()}
  {func()}
  {func()}
</View>`

You can add a loop or perform additional refactorings from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const totalImages = 10;
<View>
{ 
   (new Array(totalImages)).fill(<Image source={require('../images/image.png')}/>)
}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View>
    {() => {
        const
            longArray = new Array(7),
            image = require('../images/image.png');
        return longArray.map((k, i) => <Image key={k} source={image} />);
    }}
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that loops and returns the elements in question.

```
renderImages() {
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numrows; i++) {
        images.push(<Image source={require('../images/image.png')} />);
    }
    return images;
}
```

In the render method you would just call the function name as such:

```
{renderImages()}
```